# What permission does the "lock" group in /etc/group grant?

Tags: tty, group, lock

I'm running Fedora.

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 166, 0 Jul  4 10:50 /dev/ttyACM0
```

I was not able to access `/dev/tty/ACM0` (dynamic usb serial with an Arduino on the other end), even though I added myself to the `dialout` group. I had to either `chmod a+rw /dev/tty/ACM0` or `sudo` my programming command (`arduino` or `avrdude`).

I've recently "solved" a permission problem by cargo culting. The script `/usr/bin/arduino`, installed by my Fedora, includes a check and warning if the user is not a member of groups `dialout` and `lock`.

Adding myself to `lock` made it work. Why? I'm trying to understand the implications of this hidden ownership, and whether it applies to all the other flavors of Linux I use, but `lock` group is hard to google.

The command `sudo find / -group lock` turns up only one result: `/usr/sbin/lockdev`

Comment: Did you logout/login after adding yourself to the `dialout` group?  What about after adding yourself to the `lock` group?

Comment: No, it wasn't that. I added my user to the dialout group and re-logged in as soon as I installed arduino

Comment: I'm beginning to think its something SELinux related.

Answer (score 2):

Groups and users belong to processes. They are usually only applied at login, and then propagate to child processes. Editing `/etc/group` will not change the group of any existing process. And will not effect any new processes, unless a privileged process reads this file and adds the group (`login`, X11 display manager: X11 login system, `newgrp`, etc)

The lock thing was probably a coincidence. You probably logged out and back in again.

## To find out what files have group lock.

```
find / -mount -group lock -print | less
```

Comment: No. sorry I didn't make it clear. It was not my lack of applying the dialout group credentials.